# Git checkout -f overwrites temporary files

Tags: git

I basically followed this [guide](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) and setup my repositories. I have two folders live/ which gets updated by a hook after a push to the bare repository repo/

But there is a problem. Imagine that http://example.com/live/update.php creates a temporary file foo.temp, which is not in my local repository and it is not in the bare repository. Every time I push my changes to the bare repo, the file gets deleted.

I tried to add this file to .gitignore in my local repo. It doesn't work.

I tried to add foo.temp to my local repo but then foo.temp gets overwritten with an older version each time I push my changes.

I also can't fetch the changes made by update.php in foo.temp, since example.com/live isn't a repository.

So my question is how and where do I tell git to never delete foo.temp.

EDIT: How about making example.com/live also a repository? Fetch from example.com/live, but push to example.com/repo (bare repository)

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't routinely be using the `-f` (`--force`) option to `git checkout`...

Comment: Well, git really is not a deployment tool. I'm afraid this is what happens when you force it into a role it was not designed for...

Answer (score 0):

> I have two folders live/ which gets updated by a hook after a push to the bare repository repo/

`git checkout` doesn't touch untracked files, you can demonstrate this for yourself easily.  My bet is your hook's doing it.